# Why doesn't the setter method have any effect on other variables in my JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, constructor

Can someone please explain why the "fullName" variable in my object does not change after the "setFirstName" setter method has changed the "firstName" variable to "NewFirstName". I am aware of the correct answer to this problem but I'm confused as to why the following solution does not also work.

[This is a picture showing the below snippet being run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa27a.png)

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<script>

    var Person = function(firstAndLast) {

        let firstName = firstAndLast.split(" ")[0];
        let lastName = firstAndLast.split(" ")[1];
        let fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

        // Getters
        this.getFirstName = function() {
            return firstName;
        };
        this.getLastName = function() {
            return lastName;
        };
        this.getFullName = function() {
            return fullName;
        };

        // Setters
        this.setFirstName = function(first) {
            firstName = first;
        };
        this.setLastName = function(last) {
            lastName = last;
        };
        this.setFullName = function(name) {
            fullName = name;
        };
    };

    debugger;
    var bob = new Person('Bob Ross');

    console.log(bob.getFullName());
    bob.setFirstName("NewFirstName");
    console.log(bob.getFirstName());
    console.log(bob.getFullName());

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `fullname` variable is evaluated once during instantiation. You would want to return `firstname + ' ' + lastname` from the getter rather than `fullname` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're only calculating `fullName` once, it won't update dynamically.

You don't really want a variable for `fullName`, just a getter:

```
this.getFullName = function() {
  return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

Remove

```
let fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
```

Alternatively you can keep your variable and manually update it in both the `setFirstName` and `setLastName` functions, but really this is the kind of thing getters exist to do.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. May I ask if this behaviour is common across other Object Oriented Programming languages like Java or is this a quirk of JavaScript?

Comment: This is common. In Java this would be the same as setting a `fullName` property in the constructor, it's not going to update automatically - you're saying "When you hit this code, concat these strings as they are right now". A getter would be used to solve this problem in the same way as I've suggested.